# Possible problem with Popular Question on Server Fault on Dec 24

Tags: support, status-norepro, badges, popular-question

I logged onto Server Fault and got a popular question badge - too bad I have no questions with 1000 views.

Is something wrong with the [Popular Question](https://serverfault.com/badges/26/popular-question) badge on Server Fault, or was there a problem on Dec 24?  Maybe this was from Santa?  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure? [Supporting 1680 x 1050 resolution under Microsoft Virtual PC 2007](https://serverfault.com/questions/10964/supporting-1680-x-1050-resolution-under-microsoft-virtual-pc-2007) has had over 1000 views (1009 currently). You may have overlooked it in your question list as it is listed as "1 kviews", not "1000 views".

Comment: Oops.  That 1k fooled me, and instead of looking like a nice guy for reporting something, I look the fool.  :(

Comment: It's okay, every Christmas needs at least one fool :)